# jQuery to perform regexp multiple options

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to set a kind of captcha based on three stacked buttons which display visual different icons. The script renders three of these buttons (as below) and I need to verify that the user clicks the right icons based on the instruction given.

But to give the instruction, I need to know the which icons have been rendered, so I need jQuery to go on these three buttons, select the i id attribute and then select two (randomly) from what was loaded. For instance, in the below buttons, I would give the instruction to "Click a 'file' and a 'home'", so that the form can be submitted.

My greatest challenge now is to get jQuery to know what has been rendered and get the attribute name of each so that I can then check that the buttons have been clicked which means has now the class "active" set. I presume this can be made with a regex but not sure how. I've tried some different approaches unsuccessfully. A note to say that the "active" class is set by jQuery addClass on click, so initially the class is just "btn".

```
<button id="cb-8" type="button" class="btn active">
    <i id="icon-eye-open" class="icon-eye-open"></i>
</button>
<button id="cb-5" type="button" class="btn active">
    <i id="icon-home" class="icon-home"></i>
</button>
<button id="cb-2" type="button" class="btn active">
    <i id="icon-file" class="icon-file"></i>
</button>
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: With loaded, I meant, the ones that were generated by the php method. Although, Aktee's answer performs what I was thinking about. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No regex is required. You can do this with indexes and simple HTML attributes!

First, the HMTL

```
<div class="instructions">
  Please select <span class="choices"></span>
</div>


<button id="cb-8" type="button" class="btn captcha" data-caption="The Eye">
    <i class="icon-eye-open"></i>
</button>
<button id="cb-5" type="button" class="btn captcha" data-caption="The Home">
    <i class="icon-home"></i>
</button>
<button id="cb-2" type="button" class="btn captcha" data-caption="The File">
    <i class="icon-file"></i>
</button>
<button id="cb-1" type="button" class="btn captcha" data-caption="The Flag">
    <i class="icon-flag"></i>
</button>
<button id="cb-3" type="button" class="btn captcha" data-caption="The Tag">
    <i class="icon-tag"></i>
</button>
<button id="cb-4" type="button" class="btn captcha" data-caption="The Calendar">
    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
</button>

<br/><br/>

<button type="button" class="btn check-answer">
    <i id="icon-check" class="icon-check"></i>Check Answer
</button>
```

And the script

```
$(function() {

  // Number of buttons we want to show
  var num_show_buttons = 4;

  // Numbers of buttons that will be the answers. 
  var num_good_buttons = 2;

  // Hide all buttons by default.. and cache it. 
  var all_btn = $(".captcha").hide();

  // Get random numbers to know which buttons we're going to show
  var rand = getRandomNumbers({nums: num_show_buttons, max: all_btn.length})

  // Get random numbres to know which ones are going to be the answers
  var good_rand = getRandomNumbers({nums: num_good_buttons, max: 3})

  // Crawl through each buttons and display the chosen ones.
  $.each(rand, function(x,y) {
    var t_btn = all_btn.eq(y).addClass("visible").show();
  })

  // Crawl through each good buttons, get the captions, and add a class so we know its the good ones.
  $.each(good_rand, function(x,y) {
    var t_btn = $(".captcha.visible").eq(y).addClass("good");

    // This outputs the icons to select to the user. 
    $(".choices").append(t_btn.data('caption') + ", ");
  })


  // Everytime a buttons is clicked, add the active class. If already active, remove it.
  $(document).on("click", '.captcha', function() {
    var btn = $(this);

    if (btn.is(".active")) {
      btn.removeClass("active");
    } else {
      btn.addClass("active")
    }
  });


  $(document).on("click", ".check-answer", function() {
    // By default, the validation is false
    var validation = false;

    // If the number of active buttons equals the numbers of good buttons...
    if ($(".captcha.active").length == num_good_buttons) {
      // Set it the validation to true! But it's not over yet..
      var validation = true;

      // Let's crawl through each active one...
      $(".captcha.active").each(function(x,y) {

        // ... and check if they're good! If not, validation is false!
        if ($(".captcha.active")[x] != $(".captcha.good")[x]) {
          validation = false;
        }
      })
    }

    // Display results
    if (validation == true) {
      alert ("Good stuff!");
    } else {
      alert ("Uh oh :(");
    }

  })


});

// Functions to get x random numbers between range
function getRandomNumbers(params) {
  def = {
    nums: 10,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  }  

  opt = $.extend({}, def, params);

  var arr = []
  while(arr.length < opt.nums) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * opt.max) + opt.min
    var found=false;

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) { 
      if (arr[i] == randomnumber) { 
        found = true;
        break;
      }      
    }

    if (!found) {
      arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
    }
  }  

  return arr;
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rx7Bx/1/

Comment: Hi Aktee, thanks a lot for what you came up with. It really works as I was thinking of. I was reaching this kind of solution but got stuck in the final check for which buttons were rendered, but you came up with a better and more refined version! Thank you again.

Comment: @Mario, no problem ;) I coded it because I found it was an interesting problem.

Comment: yes, interesting and for my low experience in jQuery, it was really a challenge (I wouldn't, for now, have gone that far, for sure). May I say that you came up with a genius result! Thank you again!!